# Application post to its Wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-wall

I can't find an example of exactly what I'm trying to do, so sorry if this is a repeated question, but I have looked for the last couple of hours.

I want my Facebook app to be able to update a status or post to a wall of a page that I administrate: http://www.facebook.com/amazingjobsapp as part of a CRON job.

I just can't seem to find any examples on how to do this. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I've used to code below and now am getting:

> object(FacebookApiException)#11 (8) { ["result":protected]=> array(1) { ["error"]=> array(3) { ["message"]=> string(72) "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action" ["type"]=> string(14) "OAuthException" ["code"]=> int(200) } } ["message":protected]=> string(72) "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action" ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> int(0) ["file":protected]=> string(86)

Can someone walk me through granting my app manage_page and publish_stream permissions for page id 413282938687554 please?

EDIT 2: If I look at my graph.facebook.com/me/accounts then it shows the page id above with an access token but if I use that in my code then I still get the error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the `manages_pages` permission

```
<?php
$attachment = array(
    'message' => 'this is my message',
    'name' => 'This is my demo Facebook application!',
    'caption' => "Caption of the Post",
    'link' => 'http://mylink.com',
    'description' => 'this is a description',
    'picture' => 'http://mysite.com/pic.gif',
    'actions' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Get Search',
            'link' => 'http://www.google.com'
        )
    )
);

// To authenticated user's wall
$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', 'post', $attachment);

// To page's wall
$result = $facebook->api('page-id/feed/','post',$attachment);

// To user's wall
$result = $facebook->api('user-id/feed/','post',$attachment);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok maybe I missed something in the docs but I found the solution with is as follows:

**Note this is for people who are trying to post from a cron job.**

- Grant the manage_pages, publish_stream and offline_access perms to
  your app
- Get the access token for your page from me/accounts in the graph api explorer
- Add one simple line of code just after you initialize your fb object

  ```
  $facebook->setAccessToken("XXXXX");
  ```

Note the access token needs to be the PAGE access token you got from step 2 and remember if you de-auth the app the access token will change.

Comment: `offline_access` is deprecated – see https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: This is also necessary for posting from php. I tried <pageid>/feed?access_token=XXXXX, but that didn't work. But setAccessToken did. Why is this not mentioned anywhere else? Even answers to similar questions a year later don't address this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Application will need to ask you for `manage_pages` & `publish_stream` permissions.
2. Obtain your pages `page_access_token` from the graph api `/accounts` call.  Each page you own will have its own token listed.  This token can be saved to database or accessed at the time of need.  It is not recommended to expose or share this token.
3. Use "php-sdk" to make the post.

refer to: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

refer to: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

NOTE: To impersonate the Page when posting to the wall (i.e. post as the Page, and not the current user), you must use a Page access_token with the manage_pages and publish_stream permissions, as described under Page Access Tokens above.

***Example:**  Assumes user has installed and initialized php sdk for Facebook*

---

```
<?php
if($user){
  $vars = array(
  'message' => "message goes here",
  // you can uncomment below to enable an image with caption and link.
  //'picture' => "image",
  //'link' => "Link here",
  //'name' => "Name here",
  //'caption' => "Caption here",
  'show_error' => true,
  // comment out the access_token array below to post as a user instead of as page.
  array('access_token' => YourPageAccessToken)
);
$testpost = $facebook->api('YourPageId/feed', 'post', $vars);
}
?>
```

---

> If you find this answer helpful or is correct please remember to mark
>   it up or mark it as correct, so future users will have an easier time
>   finding answers.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, I know it seems dim but I just couldn't get my head round it - can I not physically just grant this permission rather than having to code for it?

Comment: yes, use the graph api explorer, on the right use the drop down to select you app then get access token, a permissions dialog will appear and you can grant that way.  http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=171535666239724

Comment: Hi shawn thanks for that, sorry for being dim but I manage a couple of pages how do I ensure the post goes to the right page?

Comment: ah sorry so $testpost = $facebook->api('dialog/feed', 'post', $vars); should be $testpost = $facebook->api('amazingjobsapp/feed', 'post', $vars);

Comment: yes sorry i copy pasted a snippet from my app i forgot to edit that.  i use a popup in my app.

Comment: So if I pull my pages using https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts and then use the access token thats on there will that access token change at all? The problem with this is that the script runs as a cron job so there won't actually be a user logged in at all while this is going on

Comment: that access token will only change if you uninstall your app and reauth, from my understanding.  I cache mine in a database, and update anytime i re-auth for tests. I have never really debugged the tokens to see.

Comment: Im getting an oauth exception with that saying that the user hasnt authorised this action.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15029/discussion-between-marc-fielding-and-shawn-e-carter)

Comment: Yeah I don't get that page in the graph explorer, i'd imagine its because I didnt create it but I am an admin.

Answer (score 0):

Ok where I had thought we'd fixed it we haven't the post only works when i'm actually logged into the app itself.

I'm using Shawn's code with all the permissions mentioned with the access token from "me/accounts/" for the AmazingJobs Community page.

I've definitely granted manage_pages, publish stream and offline_acess to my own facebook account i then used the graph api explorer to find the access token within accounts and cut and pasted it into my code. Any ideas?

Comment: Please merge your answers and delete one. Make and accept a definitive answer if you're not going to accept one which is already present. Answers should not be used to document your trial and error process, or further questions. Under each answer and question there's an edit link :)